# Model update is not propagated dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to sum up 2 values and display the result in the 3rd input:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    Main {{mainCtrl.foo}} <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mainCtrl.foo"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mainCtrl.foo2"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mainCtrl.foo3"/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var my = {};

my.MainCtrl = function() {
  this.foo = '1';
  this.foo2 = '2'
  this.foo3 = this.sumUp();
}

my.MainCtrl.prototype.sumUp = function() {
  return this.foo + this.foo2;
}

// register all controllers
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', my.MainCtrl);
```

My problem is that the 3rd input is set only when the document is loaded but it is not dynamically changing while typing values in first two inputs.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/K64wb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter **ng-change** for input-fields 1 and 2.
Solution for U ;) **ng-change="mainCtrl.foo3=mainCtrl.sumUp()"**
Example:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    Main {{mainCtrl.foo}} <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-change="mainCtrl.foo3=mainCtrl.sumUp()" ng-model="mainCtrl.foo"/>
    <input type="text" ng-change="mainCtrl.foo3=mainCtrl.sumUp()" ng-model="mainCtrl.foo2"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mainCtrl.foo3"/>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your view loads, it only fires the controller function once.  So it assigns foo and foo2, and then computes foo3, and then it's done.  `this.sumUp` is never called again.

You can add `ng-change="mainCtrl.foo3=mainCtrl.sumUp()"` to the input boxes like Mularski suggests.  This causes the sumUp function to run and be assigned to foo3 every time the input value changes.  I think that looks kind of messy, though.  And if you decided to add more input boxes to add up, you have to remember to put `ng-change` on all of them.

Another way to do it is to assign the sumUp function itself to foo3 like this

```
this.foo3 = this.sumUp;
```

instead of assigning the result of sumUp like you are doing (`this.foo3 = this.sumUp();`).  Then in your view, assign `foo3()` to the ng-value of the textbox:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="mainCtrl.foo3()"/>
```

(you can't assign it to ng-model because the function isn't writeable).

Now you're telling the textbox to always show the result of that function, and it will fire whenever any of its dependencies change (i.e. foo and foo2).

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/K64wb/4/).

Comment: Looks nice, but I need also sometimes to edit the foo3 input and after editing the updates are not working anymore

Comment: Well, then you probably need to go the `ng-change` route.  You could also set up a watch on `foo` and `foo2` and call `sumUp` when either of them changes.  I actually like this better than `ng-change` because it puts the code in the controller instead of the view.  Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/a7NrM/) for doing that.